# How to encode a file in UCS2-Little Endian to Windows-1251?

Tags: xml, vba, encoding, ucs2

I am trying to change the encoding from an existing file in UCS2-Little Endian to Windows-1251 from Visual Basic.

I am using the following code:

```vb
Sub convertFile()
t = AlterCharset("utf-16LE", "windows-1251")

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFullPath For Output As #iFileNum
Print #iFileNum, t

Close #iFileNum

End Sub

Private Function AlterCharset(FromChaset, ToCharset)
 Dim Bytes
 Bytes = StringToBytes(FromChaset)
 AlterCharset = BytesToString(Bytes, ToCharset)
End Function

Function StringToBytes(Charset)
 Dim Stream: Set Stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 Stream.Type = adTypeText
 Stream.Charset = Charset
 Stream.Open
 Stream.LoadFromFile sFullPath
 Stream.flush
 Stream.Position = 0
 Stream.Type = adTypeBinary
 StringToBytes = Stream.Read
 Stream.Close
 Set Stream = Nothing
End Function

Private Function BytesToString(Bytes, Charset)

 Dim Stream: Set Stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 Stream.Charset = Charset
 Stream.Type = adTypeBinary
 Stream.Open
 Stream.Write Bytes
 Stream.flush
 Stream.Position = 0
 Stream.Type = adTypeText
 BytesToString = Stream.ReadText
 Stream.Close
 Set Stream = Nothing
```

End Function

The problem is that I always get some bytes at the beginning of the text and I am not able to open it in notepad++

Could someone give a look and see what could be wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to read UCS2-Little Endian:

```
Dim fso     : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
txt = fso.OpenTextFile("txtfile.txt", 1, False, -1).ReadAll
```

Once in memory you can write to a different file